# jquery accordion not displaying arrow or plus/minus

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to implement jquery accordion in my page, accordion itself works but it does not show the arrow or plus/minus sign. my code is as follows :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src='/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>


$(function() {
        var icons = {
            header : "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            activeHeader : "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        icons: icons;
});

<div id="accordion">
<h3>tab 1</h3>
 <div>tab 1 content </div>
<h3>tab 2</h3>
<div>tab 2 content </div>
</div>
```

I did find plenty of example through out the web but nothing seems to fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably a css path issue to the correct image. Any console errors?

Comment: Use Online CSS and Crosscheck

Comment: @fauverism no console errors. I'm sure its not the css path issue cuz the layout of the accordion is formatted as defined is the  UI cssclass. Just the arrows are not showing up.

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: @fauverism there already is couple of example on jsfiddle to, only difference is they are using version 1.9.2 and i'm using 1.10.4 Im not sure if that is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after adding the following css link to the page everything worked :

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
```

But I dont understand why i need to add that when i already have a ui css file imported from the resource.

Comment: The absolute path probably had correct background-image references

Answer (score 2):

Follow the code explanation bellow:

```
// 1st - initialize accordion 
$("#accordion").accordion();
// Then set accordion header options
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", {
    'header': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
    'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/4rp0mx0p/